# Adding to a listView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I CAN ALREADY add names to a listView box. When I click the add button the first name appear, when I add a new name it adds it to the SAME LINE (ex. "john       bob      greg"). WHAT I WANT TO DO IS have every new name added appear on a new line. Any suggestions as to what might need changing on the listView??

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: I can't understand your problem. You saying "WHAT I WANT TO DO  IS have every new name added appear on a new line". Would you please post a screenshot of your `listView`?

Comment: My question is pretty clear.....

Comment: @Golf_pro90 it may be clear to you but the rest of the world doesnt really understans your problem here

Comment: @Golf_pro90 the code you posted should do exactly what you need, if it doesnt then please provide some more information about the behaviour you get.

Comment: I think What he means is that elements should be stacked vertiacally instead of that tile view. Consider using a Listbox..

Comment: @BoasEnkler that is correct. I discovered the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listView has a property called "View" which has 5 different views to choose from. Choose "List".

Answer (score 1):

as your problem you can try this..

```
listView1.Items.Add(textbox1.text); // ask a run time value
```